# GCP Logs-based Metrics don't work with regex filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to create a logs-based metric in GCP for use in an alerting rule (StackDriver, now part of GCP proper). The source are HTTPS (L7) LB logs. After a lot of trial and error, I found out that my metric doesn't work if I use a regex-based filter (note: regex-based label extraction works, after the change described below).

Concretely, if my filter looks like this:

```
httpRequest.status=403
httpRequest.requestMethod="GET"
httpRequest.requestUrl=~"^.*some/regex/pattern/.*$"
```

I do see filtered log entries after clicking "Submit Filter", and when I set up regex-based label extractors, I also see sample records/labels, but in the metrics explorer, there never is any data in the time series. However, if I change the filter to do a plain fulltext substring match, i.e.,

```
httpRequest.status=403
httpRequest.requestMethod="GET"
"some/substring/match"
```

it does work - I do see time series in the metrics explorer.

Note that this is not a timing issue, I wasn't just impatient enough. I can reliably make it work (or not) by switching between the two filters.

This is an issue for me since I do need a regex match on the request URL; substring match is not sophisticated enough, and additionally, I want to make sure only the request URL gets matched, not the referer. While I'm principally fine with a more coarse filter (even if that blows up the metric), this causes another issue in my alerting rules, as I cannot filter out non-matches -- the extracted labels have no values, and even `label !=~ [[:space:]]*` doesn't work to filter out non-matches at the alerting level, as a missing label value apparently is distinct from an empty label value. And FP alerts because of a too coarse log filter *are* quite the dealbreaker for me.

If this is expected behavior, I'd appreciate a link to the documentation where this limitation is highlighted.

Comment: Hi, please check [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-queries#searches_that_dont_do_what_you_expect). `The Logs Viewer does not support regular expression searches and there are no special wildcard characters such as * or ?, in either the basic or advanced query interfaces.`

Comment: Is your issue resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As previous comment pointed, there was an issue related with the invalid query syntax due to the usage of regular expression on the queries.

The Log Viewer does not support special wildcards characters like `*` or `?`.

You can find more invalid searches examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-queries#searches_that_dont_do_what_you_expect).